# Measuring voltage on an analog pin - What do I need to know about amperage?

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, voltage-level, safety

I'd like to measure the voltage at a test point on a stepper motor driver chip with an arduino. The voltage at this point controls the amperages to the phase coils and is adjusted to trim the driver.

I have a common ground with the driver already, I'd like to wire the drivers v-ref point to an analog input to drive an LCD showing the output amp number so I can adjust the driver.

The issue I am worried about is that with the hardware I have to test with a properly trimmed driver is pushing 0.84A.

Is this safe to do without killing the arduino board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The only thing you need to be concerned about is the voltage. It needs to be less than the Arduino Vcc.

The voltage sense circuit (analog inputs) typically have a high impedance and should draw a negligible current from the circuit being sensed. I didn't have much luck finding the actual spec for any of the AVR chips, but I did find [this answer to the question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67171/input-impedance-of-arduino-uno-analog-pins) on Electronics.StackExchange – where they say "hard to tell, the specs are incomplete, but 10 KΩ seems like a reasonable guesstimate/assumption" (I paraphrase). The reasoning is interesting and worth a read.

Comment: Awesome thank you, I'll give it a try tonight.